# Role based sharing: All Components in Salesforce and what is the best way to make existing changes

Tags: security, sharing, role-hierarchy, roles

Not sure what is the best way to ask this question

I am listing down all the places (configuration only) components where force.com platform provides option to share/assign based on Role, Role and Subordinates, Role and Internal Subordinates. For instance, I was able to list out the following. 
    • List Views
    • Folders
        ○ Email Templates
        ○ Documents
        ○ Reports
        ○ Dashboards
    • Queues
    • Public Groups
    • Approval Process (Initial submitters)
    • Email Alerts
    • Sharing Rules

Did i missed any?

In continuation, I need to change the existing Role, Role and Subordinates, Role and Internal Subordinates definition for all all the above components to a new defination (as we are redoing our Role hirarchy), what will be the best approach?

So, I have started by changing the metadata for Listview and Folders, however, for Queues & Public Groups (access level information) is not captured unlike in listview and folders.